# What is the maximum size of all attachments uploaded to Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using the Azure Devops (old VSTS) REST Api to create work items and add attachments to them. However I don't see the maximum size limit of all attachments together, if there's one.

I'm concerned because the files have a maximum of 1 MB alone but the overall size can get big really fast.

So far I'm using this piece of [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) which states the size of each attachment but not of all of them.

Comment: You may be interested in this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/object-limits?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the maximum size of all attachments uploaded to Azure Devops?

AFAIK, Azure devops only has a limit on a attachment. There is no limit to the size of all attachments. Basically, it is legitimate use is basically unlimited.

It’s based on the **Blob store** and **Meta-data store** (SQL azure database) and they are increasing. Either way it’s a lot of data and no one is close to hitting any limits.

You can check the blog [How much data can you put on VSOnline?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bharry/how-much-data-can-you-put-on-vsonline/) for some more details:

> **1) Blob store** – this is the size of the files, attachments, etc that
> are stored on the service.  The files are compressed so that affects
> the size.  The blob store is, for all intents and purposes unlimited
> (though we may from time to time impose limits to prevent abuse).
> Legitimate use is basically unlimited.

Besides, Microsoft limit activity by the resources consumed rather than a straight filesize limit, check the details:

[Rate limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rate-limits?view=azure-devops)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! This blob post was a nice find!